# Oracle SOA Suite 12c: The use of composite.xml file in Service Bus projects

Tags: oracle-service-bus, oracle-soa, sca

The composite services (SCA) are described in the file composite.xml. This is valid for SOA Suite 12c SCA composites. These composites are deployed to soa-infra container.

However, the Service Bus (SB) projects/services also contain a composite.xml file. The Service Bus services are not actually composites -- if I deploy an SB service, I won't find it amongst composites. I can find the SB service only in SB console (or via Enterprise Manager, which in my opinion looks at the same place).

I understand that integration of SCA and Service Bus (both being part of SOA Suite) is still in progress, I wonder if Service Bus services are going to be implemented as composites in a future SAO Suite release, or what is the purpose of having composite.xml within the SB project. Can you please advise?

The SB development guide gives no indication.